# After Migration from v2.9 to 3.5 - some entries added into an entry-relation-field get added twice after saving

Tags: structure, migration, entries-field, sql

We migrated a craft cms site with 3 locales from v2.9 to 3.5
We have a section with a field of type "Entries".
When editing the entry, and adding certain entries to this field, those get added twice after saving.
After investigating, these relations dont show up twice in DB, but the SQL-query returns them twice.

i created a test template to narrow down the SQL:

`{% set infos = craft.entries.id(497).one().contextInterneLinksRel.all() %}`

the sql resulting into double showing the relation:

```
SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`fieldLayoutId`, `elements`.`uid`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_sites`.`id` AS `siteSettingsId`, `elements_sites`.`slug`, `elements_sites`.`siteId`, `elements_sites`.`uri`, `elements_sites`.`enabled` AS `enabledForSite`, `entries`.`sectionId`, `entries`.`typeId`, `entries`.`authorId`, `entries`.`postDate`, `entries`.`expiryDate`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `content`.`title`, `content`.`field_absenderAuthorText`, `content`.`field_adminSpracheinstellungen`, `content`.`field_aktuellerStatus`, `content`.`field_medienmitteilungAnriss`, `content`.`field_showInList`, `content`.`field_begruessungstext`, `content`.`field_betreff`, `content`.`field_copyrightInformationenIntranet`, `content`.`field_medienmitteilungDatumVeroeffentlichung`, `content`.`field_deMailchimpNewsletterGdpr`, `content`.`field_deMailchimpNewsletterHoneypot`, `content`.`field_deMailchimpNewsletterUrl`, `content`.`field_globalEmailKursanmeldungenAlternativ`, `content`.`field_einleitungstext`, `content`.`field_globalAdresse`, `content`.`field_fileAlt`, `content`.`field_automatischesInhaltsverzeichnis`, `content`.`field_forumRBeschreibung`, `content`.`field_adminBildFocusCSSPosition`, `content`.`field_noTransform`, `content`.`field_blogAnrissText`, `content`.`field_fileCopyright`, `content`.`field_fileDescription`, `content`.`field_definitiveAnmeldung`, `content`.`field_einfacherInhalt`, `content`.`field_globalEmailKursanmeldungen`, `content`.`field_globalEmailVeranstaltungsanmeldungen`, `content`.`field_contextExterneLinks`, `content`.`field_portalLinkUrl`, `content`.`field_forumRAusgabe`, `content`.`field_kampagnenBoxInhalt`, `content`.`field_kampagnenBoxLink`, `content`.`field_kampagnenBoxLinkText`, `content`.`field_keineAnmeldungMoeglich`, `content`.`field_keinHeaderBild`, `content`.`field_kontaktFuerKurse`, `content`.`field_kontaktFuerVeranstaltungen`, `content`.`field_kostenMitglied`, `content`.`field_kostenNichtMitglied`, `content`.`field_kursKosten`, `content`.`field_notShowInNav`, `content`.`field_portalInhalt`, `content`.`field_portalLinkText`, `content`.`field_portalTitel`, `content`.`field_produktBeschreibung`, `content`.`field_produktPreis`, `content`.`field_produktReferenznummer`, `content`.`field_produktSteuer`, `content`.`field_globalRechteSpalteFusszeile`, `content`.`field_redirectUrl`, `content`.`field_regionkuerzel`, `content`.`field_seitenLayout`, `content`.`field_seitenueberschrift`, `content`.`field_metatagDescription`, `content`.`field_seitezugriffe`, `content`.`field_metatagTitle`, `content`.`field_frMailchimpNewsletterGdpr`, `content`.`field_frMailchimpNewsletterHoneypot`, `content`.`field_frMailchimpNewsletterUrl`, `content`.`field_fragenBemerkungen`, `content`.`field_itMailchimpNewsletterGdpr`, `content`.`field_itMailchimpNewsletterHoneypot`, `content`.`field_itMailchimpNewsletterUrl`, `content`.`field_newsletterausgabe`, `content`.`field_isShopStartseite`, `content`.`field_sprachenAbgeschlossen`, `content`.`field_subnavigationImmerZeigen`, `content`.`field_suchresultatText`, `content`.`field_test`, `structureelements`.`root`, `structureelements`.`lft`, `structureelements`.`rgt`, `structureelements`.`level`, `structureelements`.`structureId`
FROM (SELECT `elements`.`id` AS `elementsId`, `elements_sites`.`id` AS `elementsSitesId`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`, `structureelements`.`structureId`
FROM `rhe_elements` `elements`
INNER JOIN `rhe_entries` `entries` ON `entries`.`id` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `rhe_elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `rhe_content` `content` ON (`content`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`) AND (`content`.`siteId` = `elements_sites`.`siteId`)
LEFT JOIN `rhe_structureelements` `structureelements` ON (`structureelements`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`) AND (EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM `rhe_structures`
WHERE (`id` = `structureelements`.`structureId`) AND (`dateDeleted` IS NULL)))
INNER JOIN `rhe_relations` `relations` ON (`relations`.`targetId` = `elements`.`id`) AND ((`relations`.`sourceId`=497) AND (`relations`.`fieldId`='85')) AND ((`relations`.`sourceSiteId` IS NULL) OR (`relations`.`sourceSiteId`=1))
WHERE (`elements_sites`.`siteId`=1) AND (`elements`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (((`elements`.`enabled`=TRUE) AND (`elements_sites`.`enabled`=TRUE)) AND (`entries`.`postDate` <= '2020-11-24 15:05:00') AND ((`entries`.`expiryDate` IS NULL) OR (`entries`.`expiryDate` > '2020-11-24 15:05:00'))) AND (`elements`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL) AND (`elements`.`draftId` IS NULL) AND (`elements`.`revisionId` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `relations`.`sortOrder`) `subquery`
INNER JOIN `rhe_entries` `entries` ON `entries`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `rhe_elements` `elements` ON `elements`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `rhe_elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsSitesId`
INNER JOIN `rhe_content` `content` ON `content`.`id` = `subquery`.`contentId`
LEFT JOIN `rhe_structureelements` `structureelements` ON (`structureelements`.`elementId` = `subquery`.`elementsId`) AND (`structureelements`.`structureId` = `subquery`.`structureId`)
INNER JOIN `rhe_relations` `relations` ON (`relations`.`targetId` = `elements`.`id`) AND ((`relations`.`sourceId`=497) AND (`relations`.`fieldId`='85')) AND ((`relations`.`sourceSiteId` IS NULL) OR (`relations`.`sourceSiteId`=1))
ORDER BY `relations`.`sortOrder`
```

Here is an example for a double from the result:

[image]

The only difference are in columns: `root,lft,rgt,structureId` the rest is all the same.

[image]

It seems there are 2 rows in table `structureelements` for this entry, that gets added twice.

[image]

What does it mean? Any help is apreciated, thx.

Comment: Back up and try running `./craft utils/repair/section-structure yourStructureHandle`

Comment: thx, works like a charme!

Comment: Great, I'll add it as an answer then!

Answer (score 1):

Take a database backup first to be on the safe side then run:

```
./craft utils/repair/section-structure yourStructureHandle
```

See documentation - https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#utils-repair-section-structure